# SQL count number at specified location in spring

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have MySQL database where I store information from reservation system. I want to count one specified value which is stored in columns "places" which are strings.
The strings looks like this:

```
a:3:{i:1626;a:2:{s:10:".........
a:5:{a:2:{s:10:{s:10:...........
a:15:{i:1364;a:2:s:10:"place_....
```

The value which I am looking for is the digit after start of the string "a:" and before the next symbol ":". Basically, in this case, I would like to count 3+5+15. Is it possible to use some specified regex in MySQL and if yes how would you do this? Thanks in advance guys. I really have no idea how to use this kind of REGEXP.

Comment: It would be safer to fetch the string, parse it, _then_ act on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select sum(substring(col, 3) + 0)
from t;
```

The `substring()` extracts the substring starting at the third character (after the initial "a:").  The `+ 0` converts the leading digits to a number.